# Origin of Humans in Hinduism

Tags: human

Different cultures/religion give a different story on the origin of Humans.

Christianity speaks about Adam being the first human.

Greek mythology says Zeus created first human in his form.

Is there a similar story to the origin of humans in Hinduism.? Which books deals about it.?

Or Does Hinduism support Darwin's theory of humans evolving from monkeys(lower life forms).?

Comment: Does Hinduism support Darwin's theory of humans evolving from lower life forms? No. In fact [Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117939.html) directly contradicts Darwin's theory. E.g., the Upanishad says humans evolved prior to ants but according to [this article](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-germany-ant-idUSLG53732420080916) ants have been around for 120 million years whereas the [earliest modern humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens#Origin) are only 200,000 years old.

Comment: "Is there a similar story to the origin of humans in Hinduism.?" - Brahma created prajapatis & manus to initiate the creation process. swayambhuva manu and sataroopa were the first mithunam (couple). "Which books deals about it.?" several puranas, manusmriti  and upanishads that talk about creation. "Does Hinduism support Darwin's theory of humans evolving from monkeys(lower life forms).?" - Hinduism elevates post-darwinian evolution; i.e. evolution of the human/soul to super-human states.